# Using Multiple Conditions to create Resources in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a cloud AWS Formation Template, like this:

```
Parameters:
   FirewallConditionValue:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: "/mlops/deploy/firewallParamValue"

   EcrApiConditionValue:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: "/mlops/deploy/ecr.api"

Conditions:
   CreateVpcEndpoint: !Not [!Equals [!Ref FirewallConditionValue, 'ReuseInfra']]
   EcrApiEndpoint: !Equals [!Ref EcrApiConditionValue, 'false']

Resources:
   ECRAPIVPCE:
    Condition: !Or
      - !Condition EcrApiEndpoint
      - !Condition CreateVpcEndpoint
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.ecr.api'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

I want to create the resources if either of the condition is True, But when I run this, it is giving `Template format error: Every Condition member must be a string..`

Is something missing here?

Comment: You can't reference other resources in conditions as CFN evaluates them before stack creation. You could try using a mapping in your condition and pass the resolved parameters to CFN directly when triggering deploy (depending on your use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new condition for your `Or` statement in `Conditions` section, e.g. `ErcAPiOrEndponit`, Then in your `Resources` you will referer to that new condition:

```
Resources:
   ECRAPIVPCE:
    Condition: ErcAPiOrEndponit
```